# Angular Editable Combobox

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have a table in which one of the column is "Justification". It is a drop-down field but also needs the ability to add new option if appropriate option is not available. Also there should be validation so that user is allowed fixed number of characters(eg: 25).
eg: Options available - red, blue, yellow
I should be able to add green in that field.
After lot of research, I found few examples in AngularJS but nothing in Angular 7.

Example: [Editable ComboBox using bootstrap/angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629404/editable-combobox-using-bootstrap-angularjs/24976710#24976710)

Comment: Hi. What's your actual question? Please keep in mind that asking for recommendations or off site resources is considered off topic.

Comment: My question is straight-forward - how to create Editable Combobox?

Comment: Just look for a "autocomplete" or "typeHead", then in blur you can add the value if it's not jet in the options. See an example using material autocomplete in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o72pso?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete above requirement by using primeNG lib.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete